# Can't install nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2 on Arch Linux,as metasploit installation can't proceed without it.
I got the following output:

```
[ blackarch Downloads ]# gem install ./nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem                       
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ./nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151103-1360-1u3d2zo.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/patch.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:279:in `block in execute': Failed to complete patch task (RuntimeError)
    from /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `chdir'
    from /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `execute'
    from extconf.rb:311:in `block in patch'
    from extconf.rb:308:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:308:in `patch'
    from /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:278:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:475:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I've tried every possible solution I found, either locally installation or gem install nokogiri doesn't work...

Answer (score 9):

You can try :

`bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

`bundle install`

Or you can reseach sth on
[nokogiri doc](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2 -- --use-system-libraries
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

did it for me

Answer (score 3):

If you are using macOS Mojave, Xcode 10 on macOS Mojave moves the system headers out of `/usr/include` and so Nokogiri will fail to build. 
Here is a workaround from [nokogiri official installing guide](https://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Answer (score -3):

You should update your gemfile with the nokogiri gem

> gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8'

after updating your Gemfile with the line of code above run:

> bundle install